# How to test a component with Froala Editor in Karma for Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, froala

I am using Froala Editor in my component. The editor is working fine when I run the website. But, the spec.ts file is generating this error.

> TypeError: *this.*$element.froalaEditor is not a function

Any solution?

The onAddPost function is getting covered, no problems with that. But, the test case is failing because of the error regarding Froala editor itself.

Comment: could you add your spec.ts file content?

Comment: Are you using angular-froala-wysiwyg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as i see you **do not use template** of component in your test, so you can just remove `FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule` from imports, and add **template override** for your component, like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   ....
})
.compileComponents()
.overrideComponent(PostsAddComponent, {
    set: {
        template: ""
    }
});
```

Since your component **won't have template**, you **won't use froala components & directives**, and it **won't access** this **global script** and error should disappear. Hope that helps.